# Tower of Hanoi Recursive Solution that Modifies Lists at Each Stage of Recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a recursive solution for the Tower of Hanoi problem that actually modifies list objects representing the 3 towers at each recursive step. If slicing lists didn't create copies, the code would look something like this:

```
def hanoi_solver(T, I, A):
''' assumes T is the target list and is empty
    A is the auxillary list and is empty
    I is the initial list with values [1, 2, ..., n]
    with the smaller numbers representing wider disks'''

    length = len(I)
    if length == 1:
        T.append(I.pop())
    elif length >1:
        hanoi_solver(A, I[1: (length+1)], T) 
        T.append(I.pop())
        hanoi_solver(T, A, I)
```

However, since slicing makes copies, the code fails. Is there any way in python to create an alias to a subset of a list? That is, is there a mechanism similar to slicing that doesn't create a copy? If that's not implemented in Python, is there any other way to SOLVE THE PROBLEM RECURSIVELY that still modifies lists at each stage? See example illustrating the goal below.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# Goal is to create b st b points to elements 2, 3, 4 in a
b = a[1:4]
b.pop()
# Since slicing creates a copy a remains unchanged when b is modified.
# Thus only b is affected.
print a
print b
# prints
# a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# b = [2, 3]

# would like to print 
# a = [1, 2, 3]
# b = [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a helper function hanoi_helper(T,I,A,k) where the new parameter indicates how many disks are to be moved from I to T. Rather than slicing - modify k in the recursive calls. Then your overall function would simply be

```
def hanoi_solver(T,I,A):
    hanoi_helper(T,I,A,len(I))
```